# routerLink for the child components redirecting to Page Not Found works

Tags: angular, angular6, angular7, angular-routing

I'am trying to pass UserId to one of component using routerLink. and  redirected to below URL. but the route displaying Page not found works message. 
http://localhost:4200/admin/distributors/edit/3

also included component in routing module. 
path: 'distributors/edit:UserId', component: AddDistributorComponent,

above i'am getting UserId but why it is showing Page not found message.

Please Help.. Thanks in advance.

distributors.component.html

```
<button class="btn btn-info" title="Edit" [routerLink]="['/admin/distributors/edit', usr.UserId]"></button>
```

admin.routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
    import { AdminDashboardComponent } from './admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.component';
    import { DistributorsComponent } from './distributors/distributors.component';
    import { AddDistributorComponent } from './add-distributor/add-distributor.component';
    import { AuthGuard } from '../auth/auth.guard';
    const routes: Routes = [
        {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
          {
          path: '',
          children: [
            { path: 'distributors', component: DistributorsComponent },
            { path: 'distributors/create', component: AddDistributorComponent },
            { path: 'distributors/edit:UserId', component: AddDistributorComponent },
            { path: '', component: AdminDashboardComponent }
          ],
        }
      ]
      }
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
        providers: [],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

add-distributor.component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
    const id = this.actroute.snapshot.paramMap.get('UserId');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having a extra `children` in **admin.routing.module.ts**

```
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { AdminComponent } from './admin/admin.component';
    import { AdminDashboardComponent } from './admin-dashboard/admin-dashboard.component';
    import { DistributorsComponent } from './distributors/distributors.component';
    import { AddDistributorComponent } from './add-distributor/add-distributor.component';
    import { AuthGuard } from '../auth/auth.guard';
    const routes: Routes = [
        {
        path: 'admin',
        component: AdminComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        children: [
            { path: 'distributors', component: DistributorsComponent },
            { path: 'distributors/create', component: AddDistributorComponent },
            { path: 'distributors/edit/:UserId', component: AddDistributorComponent },
            { path: '', component: AdminDashboardComponent }
        ]
      }
    ];

    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
        providers: [],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AdminRoutingModule { }
```

And to get the params I usually use the subscription:

```
 this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
        this.paramId = params.UserId;
 });
```

Comment: ufffffff..found error in this line. it should be  { path: 'distributors/edit/:UserId', component: AddDistributorComponent },